# questions about self adjoint operators on hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following test prep questions:

1. Let $(H,\langle,\rangle)$ be a hilbert space, $T\in L(H)$, $T\not \equiv 0$, and $T$ self-adjoint.  Show that $T^n$ is self-adjoint and not null
2. Let $A\in L(H)$, with $A$ self-adjoint ($H$ as above).  Prove that $$\bigg(\langle Ax,x\rangle=0, \forall x\in H \bigg)\iff A\equiv 0.$$
3. $H$  as in 1, $T\in L(H)$.

   a)  Show that if the scalar field is $\mathbb C$, then $$T \text{ is self-adjoint } \iff \forall x\in H, \langle Tx,x\rangle\in\mathbb R.$$

   b) Show that if the scalar field is $\mathbb R$, then $$T \text{ is self-adjoint } \iff \forall x,y\in H, \langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle Ty,x\rangle.$$

For 1, if $T$ wasn't null, then clearly $T^n$ isn't null, right? I don't know how to show that it's also self-adjoint, though.

I'm guessing 2 is an easy use of the definitions of self-adjoint.

No idea about 3a.

For 3b... isn't that trivial? isn't that just the same as the definition of self-adjoint?

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem? Most of these properties follow from that.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that $T^n$ is *clearly* not null. Think for instance of the operator $\pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 }$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which squares to zero, so the property is definitely not true for all operators.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong we JUST learned it in class, so I can look it up and remember, but I'm not familiar enough with it to use comfortably (or know what to do for this particular question).

Comment: @fuglede Hmm... you're right.  So what's special about this one? being self-adjoint?

Comment: Hm, I guess it's possible to avoid using the spectral theorem. Some of the answers might be a little messier...

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong It's ok, TECHNICALLY we are allowed to use the spectral theorem.  I'm just personally not too familiar with it, but I suppose it would be good exercise to work with it. I'll try to see if that leads me anywhere.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong actually, I ended up doing almost all of these questions without requiring the spectral theorem.  Right now I'm only missing the proof that $T$ is not nilpotent....

Comment: Here's a hint for that one: if $Tx \neq 0$ for some $x$, then $\langle T^2 x, x \rangle = \| Tx\|^2 \neq 0$. Iterate this for higher powers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For complex Hilbert spaces, the inner-product is determined from the norm by the polarization identity
$$
               (x,y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}\|x+i^{n}y\|^{2}, \;\;\; i = \sqrt{-1}.
$$